# What is the derivative of this function: $\frac {d}{dx}x^{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> What is the derivative of the following function?
>   $$\frac {d}{dx}x^{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}$$
>   Here, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function.

**I tried:** $$\frac {d}{dx} x^x=\frac {d}{dx} e^{x \ln x}=x^x (\ln x +1)+C$$

But, here $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ is problematic for me.

Comment: When $x$ is not an integer, then the floor function is locally constant, so treat it as a constant when differentiating. At integers, you need to use the limit definition of derivative, and there's no guarantee the limit will exist. (Try comparing right and left limits of the difference quotient.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x\in[n,n+1)$, where $n$ is an integer. Then
$$
f(x)=x^n
$$
and so $f$ coincides with $x^n$ over the open interval $(n,n+1)$. Hence $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$ for $x\in(n,n+1)$.

Thus, for noninteger $x$,
$$
f'(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor x^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}
$$
The problem is now to see whether $f$ is differentiable at integers. But, if $n\ne0$ is an integer
$$
\lim_{x\to n^+}x^{\lfloor x\rfloor}=\lim_{x\to n^+}x^n=n^n
$$
whereas
$$
\lim_{x\to n^-}x^{\lfloor x\rfloor}=\lim_{x\to n^-}x^{n-1}=n^{n-1}
$$
The limits are different when $n\ne1$. Also
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=1
\qquad
\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=-\infty
$$
This shows the function is not continuous at the integers $\ne1$, so not differentiable either.

Now try and see if the derivative exists at $x=1$.

Comment: Can you axplain me, Why we must find $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}f(x)$..I know the first limit equals $1$. But W.A. gives me the second limit $+\infty$ ..Is it important to know this? Thank you.

Comment: @Beginner I'm analyzing continuity at $0$, a method is to compute the limits from the left and from the right. The limit from the left is $\lim_{x\to0^-}x^{-1}=-\infty$, because for $-1<x<0$ we have $\lfloor x\rfloor=-1$. I don't know why Wolframalpha yields $\infty$. If you don't accept $0^0=1$, then the function would not even be defined at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The function has discontinuities at integer values of $x$. Other than that, you can evaluate the derivatives using $\frac{d}{dx}x^a=ax^{a-1}$ because $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is constant for $a < x < a+1$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. To summarize, the derivative of $x^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ when it exists is
$$\lfloor x \rfloor x^{\lfloor x \rfloor-1}.$$

Comment: But if $0 < x < 1$ then $\lfloor x \rfloor x^{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1} = \lfloor x \rfloor = 0$, no special handling needed.

Comment: @Beginner It's not globally constant, but it's *locally* constant everywhere except at integers, and differentiability is a local property.

Comment: @Connor Harris hmm I understood..$x$ only must be $a<x<a+1$??

Comment: Also, the derivative does not exist at a single integer, to see this consider to adjacent intervals $I_1=(a,a+1)$ and $I_2=(a+1,a+2)$. $f'(a+1)=a(a+1)^{a-1}$ at $I_1$, and $f'(a+1)=(a+1)(a+1)^a$ at $I_2$. These two values are equal only if there is an $a$ such that $a^2+a+1=0$, which is impossible for any integer.

Comment: @ConnorHarris Thanks. Removed the statement.

Comment: @Math Lover is this function only differentiable on interval $a<x<a+1?$

Comment: @Beginner Yes for all $a < x < a+1$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. That is, for all non-integer reals.

Comment: Okay. I understood.. But , Only I didnt know Why $x$ can not equal an integer?

Comment: By the way +1) thanks for answer.

Comment: @Beginner Plot the graph for $0 < x < 2$ and see what is happening at $x=1$. For a mathematical proof, see cansomeonehelpmeout comment.

Comment: I thought , $x \in [2,3), [3,4)...$

Comment: @Beginner The limits from **both sides** must be equal. If you consider $x \to 1^{-}$, the derivative limit is $0$. But if you consider $x \to 1^{+}$, the limit is $1$. So the derivative at $x = 1$ does not exist.

Comment: Aha. Moment..Now, I understood..:) off topic question: Is the limit exist the right and left limit must be equal ,right?? For example, $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 10$ doesn't exist. $-\infty ≠+\infty$??

Comment: @Beginner Yes, the limits from both sides must be equal.